# Should questions regarding bible study methodology be considered on-topic or off-topic for Christianity.SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

Stemming from [this meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3830/off-topic-are-you-guys-serious/3834#3834) about the specific question: [If we want to know what the Bible says about an issue, what methods can help us to find all the relevant scriptures?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30541/if-we-want-to-know-what-the-bible-says-about-an-issue-what-methods-can-help-us) - which seems to have generated a diverse response from the community, it is suggested that we discuss questions of this type more generally. Can questions of a similar nature be on-topic for this site and if so, what principles will ensure they are well-formed?

Answer (score 3):

These questions are fine as long as the're focused and answerable. For example I think all these questions would be acceptable:

- What is the 'Swedish Method' for studying the Bible?
- What is the history of the 'Swedish Method'?
- Why do some people say it is dangerous to do word studies?
- What is the Biblical/traditional basis for the historical-grammatical/analogical interpretation approaches?
- What interpretative methods did Billy Graham usually use?

Comment: I think all of these would/should be on-topic and are interesting.

Comment: I think the last one is probably not answerable, unless Billy Graham is here to answer for himself.  If the question was modified slightly, to which ones does he promote, or something similar, it might be answerable.

Comment: It may or may not be, depending on what he has said. A lot of famous preachers do talk about their methodology. But anyways, it was just an example I had to think of quickly!

Comment: I actually upvoted before I googled, but if I could, I would upvote again just for introducing me to the Swedish method.