# Should questions about the use of scriptural or religious study guides be on-topic for this site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, help-center

Referring to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/63914/what-do-bible-lexicons-like-strongs-mean-when-they-use-the-phrase-by-extens?noredirect=1#comment173439_63914) and related to [this Meta post](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3838/should-questions-regarding-bible-study-methodology-be-considered-on-topic-or-off).

A question was asked about the use of lexicons (specifically mentioning Strong's Concordance).  I felt it would be on-topic, but Lee Woofenden pointed out that it was a linguistic question and therefore not a question about Christianity.

Specifically in relation to the linked question, after reviewing what the phrase "by extension" means from a dictionary perspective, I realized that Strong's Concordance (and likely other lexicons) was using the phrase outside the definition and more in the way I explain in my answer to the question.  This means there's a "Christian twist" to how the phraseology is used specific to the concordance.  Said another way, asking the question on English.SE would likely have resulted in the wrong answer because the site focuses on official definitional language and not contextual meanings.

This would suggest there isn't a better place to ask the question.

**Question:** And that raises the question (especially in light of the linked question about study methodologies) about whether or not questions about Christian-oriented study guides and resources would or should be on-topic on this site regardless of the specific aspect of the question?  In other words is, "I found the phrase X in Strong's Concordance, what does it mean?" on- or off-topic?

I appreciate the community's insight as it will improve my judgement with future questions.